# AngularJS: Can not change location using routes

Tags: javascript, session, angularjs

I am learning Angular and this is what I try to do

- Add a session on a button click of 'Add Session'
- Delete session on a button click of 'Delete Session' and redirect it to different page

I have a demo here, which says on console that `I am routing`, but doesn't routes it

The relevant code is

```
 $scope.deleteSession = function() {
    // console.log('deleting session');
    $cookieStore.remove('session');
    updateSession();
    $scope.route();
  };

  $scope.route = function () {
    console.log('I am routing');
    $location.path('/route');
  }
```

The full code/demo is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DHev6mhrvdqhXQU5047J?p=preview)

Please help me understanding my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ng-view` attribute to your `body` :

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-view >
```

Have a look: http://plnkr.co/edit/6eIt6F?p=preview